# How to make different buttons in one scene change to their own specified scene uppon click?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've tried different tutorials but the scenes won't change for any of the ones in that scene. I have a scene that goes before this one and it only has one button that changes scenes and it works, but not the buttons in my scene with multiple buttons. And I've added all the scenes in the build settings.

This is the code I used for the button in the scene that has only one

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void playGame()
    {
          SceneManager. LoadScene(Scene Manager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }
}
```

Then I draged the script to Canvas> went to button> added on click> draged canvas to spot under Runtime Only > NewBehaviourScript > playGame ()

Comment: are your new scenes added on the player settings build?

Comment: @Lotan I forgot to mention that but I did add them to build settings.

Comment: How about let each button load the according scene by index or name?

Comment: @derHugo I thought that's what my code did. And I tried using the name of the scene instead but it didn't work either.

Comment: No that's not what your code does ... you code does: Click on any button will simply load the next scene regardless which scene you are currently in or which button was pressed ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
public void playGame(int levelIndex)
    {
          SceneManager.LoadScene(levelIndex);
    }
```

and reassign your script to your buttons. after each assignment, you can enter your level index on your own button.

Comment: That worked but its got one small weird problem, I want to have the buttons near the bottom of the camera view but they won't send me to another scene unless I move them away from the bottom.